# Loading data via `dataLoader` in serial AmCharts does not renders the chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, amcharts

I'm using `dataLoader` for retrieving data in AmChart from **PHP/MySql** backend. 
However the simple `serial` bar chart is generated but don't know what is the problem with rendering graphs, graphs are not getting generated.

Then with another try using ajax call I've done re-parsing of `JSON` response to  object via loop just like `generateChartData()`, it's the same data. But still chart is not getting rendered.

These options I've passed to `dataLoader`

```
"dataLoader": {
       "url": 'data.php',
       "format": "json"
}
```

In ajax call I call  `chart.validateData()` but this is not working. What can done to solve this?

setting `async` option for ajax request `false` gives warning and doesn't work too.

Here is the **js** code `app.js`:

```
var chartData = [];
loadChartData();
function loadChartData() {
var time = new Date();
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
        var cur = new Date();
        var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
        data.forEach(function(d, i) {
            chartData.push({
                date: d.date,
                visits: parseInt(d.visits, 10)
            });
        });
        // alert('Request Completed in '+ (cur - time)+ ' mili seconds');
        console.log(chartData.length);
        // chart.validateData();
    }
};
ajax.open('GET', 'data.php', true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
ajax.send();
}

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"marginRight": 80,
// "dataLoader": {  
//         "url": "data.php",
//         "format": "json"
// }, this doesn't work too!
"dataProvider": chartData,
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
"valueAxes": [{
    "position": "left",
    "title": "Energy Generated"
}],
"graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "fillAlphas": 0.4,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "balloonText": "<div style='margin:5px; font-size:19px;'><b>[[value]]kWh</b></div>"
}],
"chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "scrollbarHeight": 80,
    "backgroundAlpha": 0,
    "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
    "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
    "graphFillAlpha": 0,
    "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
    "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
    "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
    "autoGridCount": true,
    "color": "#AAAAAA"
},
"chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "JJ:NN, DD MMMM",
    "cursorPosition": "mouse"
},
"categoryField": "date",
"categoryAxis": {
    "minPeriod": "mm",
    "parseDates": true
},
});

// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "dataUpdated" event
function zoomChart() {
// different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates,     zoomToCategoryValues
   chart.zoomToIndexes( chart.dataProvider.length - 250, chart.dataProvider.length - 100);
}

zoomChart();
```

And here is my **php** code `data.php`

```
$link = new mysqli( "localhost", "root", "", "test" );
if ( $link->connect_errno ) {
   die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// Fetch the data
$query = "SELECT *
          FROM daily_visits
          ORDER BY date ASC";

 $result = $link->query( $query );

// All good?
if ( !$result ) {
     // Nope
     $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . $link->error . "\n";
     $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die( $message );
 }

 $data = array();
 while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
     $data[] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode( $data );
 // Close the connection
 mysqli_close($link);
```

And the returned `json` looks like

```
[{"date":"2016-09-03","visits":"16"},{"date":"2016-09-03","visits":"49"},...]
```

Comment: Please post your complete code and data returned by data.php. Otherwise, we can just guess what could be wrong.

Comment: @martynasma updated the question

Comment: @martynasma finally found one solution. I had to change the data type of `date` field from `DATE` to `DATETIME` and everything works, but still i see some vertical lines are generated which doesn't point to any value. I wonder if it could be removed.

Comment: If you went to DATETIME fields, it means your dates now come in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS. Did you update your `dataDateFormat` setting accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "dataProvider": chartData from makeChart, when using dataloader.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some more details on how this solves the problem? That way, your answer will be a bigger benefit to anyone else reading this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the instance of the chart:

```
let chartInstance = AmChart.makeCharts(...);
(<any>this.chartInstance).dataProvider = parsedArray; // yes, here we update the dataProvider directly
```

If anyone doesn't understand this, please leave a message here.

Comment: Thx @Julien Lopez My poor English